# Is it possible to load other database in Android devices?

Tags: android

I know that SQLite is the default database loaded in all Android devices. What other databases can we use in Android devices, and how do we load them on the device?

Additionally, as per my knowledge, SQLite is using phone memory to store all the data. Can a memory card be used for storing the data instead? How / where would I specify this location?

Answer (score 0):

There are Android versions of some projects available. For instance CouchDB has an Android version they've been working on:

http://www.couchone.com/android

Generally though your question is very subjective, so it's unlikely you'll get very many answers on Stack Overflow. You might be better off asking a new question with some specifics about what you're looking for, like what makes a 'good' database for you? Space optimized? Speed? Particular features for query syntax? Your existing question is too broad.

Answer (score 0):

In the CreateDatabase call, you can specify the full path to the SD card. If you don't provide the path, it goes into /data/data/your.app.name/databases.

There are other commercial and OSS alternatives to SQLite if you wish to investigate them. Oracle has Berkeley DB and another is Versant.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer. 
If another database can be used, how to install it on the device ?

Comment: I haven't used either product--I'm just aware of their existence. Oracle's product page says it's a static library that adds about 1MB to your application.  http://www.oracle.com/us/products/database/berkeley-db/index.html